# How to declare multiple arrays with similar name in a for loop?

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, floating-point, char

I want to declare 32 1d arrays with name **efficiency_module_cmp_%d_x**, %d goes from 1 to 16 and **efficiency_module_cmp_%d_y**, %d goes from 1 to 16.
I am using the following code to do this but this is not working. what is wrong with this:

```
char array_name[100];
char array_name1[100];


for ( int i=0; i<16;i++)
{

    sprintf(array_name,"efficiency_module_cmp_%d_x",i+1); 
    float array_name[n] ; 
    sprintf(array_name1,"efficiency_module_cmp_%d_y",i+1); 
    float array_name1[n] ; 

}
```

Suggest a possible solution.

Comment: You can't create names of types or objects at run-time in C or  C++. Why do you think you need to do this?

Comment: He could in macro

Comment: @Flip Not at run time.

Comment: `std::map` could be one solution.

Comment: Runtime not but there is a way to do what he want via macro

Comment: Also inside a loop the scope of the variable ends.

Comment: @Filip " there is a way to do what he want via macro" - then post an answer illustrating it.

Comment: Why not `std::array<std::array<float, 100>, 16>` ?

Comment: Why are you trying to define arrays with the same name as arrays that already exist, but with different types? Since the example is short and you took the time to show it, I'm assuming it's relevant.

Comment: @NeilButterworth take a look please

Comment: What i am trying to  do is following:

Comment: What i am trying to  do is following: I have four .txt files. Each of them have 1 column and 16 rows . I want to store the number in first row of each of the files in one array say array1, second row in each of the files in array2 and so on upto 16th row in each of the files in array16. for that i have to first declare 16 1d arrays with name array1, array2, array3 .... . Other sixteen corresponding pair of arrays contain the file number . so i have to declare in total 32 1d arrays with names say array1-array16 and array1_y- array16_y

Comment: Sounds like you want multi-dimensional arrays, or better vectors or maps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot create names of objects at run-time (C++ is statically typed). Instead, you can make an vector (or any other container) of arrays, and push your arrays to the back of the container like so:

```
#include <vector>
int main()
{
    std::vector<char*> vectorOfArrays;
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        vectorOfArrays.push_back(new char[10]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Then you can access one of your arrays like this: `vectorOfArrays[3];`

Comment: Thanks , I am  able to do what i wanted using the above solution. It Worked.